# Add Numbers by generating random tasks containing numbers

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
public TestClass{

     public  Task<int> GetRandomNumber() {
                return Task.FromResult(new Random().Next(0, 1500));
            }
    }



public class Default
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TestClass();
            List<int> adddata = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
              var  result = Task.Run(() => test.GetRandomNumber());
              Console.WriteLine("The values that will be added are :{0}", result.Result);
              adddata.Add(result.Result);    
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The value is :{0}", adddata.Sum(v => v));
     }
}
```

The problem is random number returns same numbers,68 ,68, 122 when it should return distinct number what am I doing wrong I am trying to learn about how to use Task in C#.Thanks!

Comment: Btw. even if you don't create a new `Random` object each time (and solve the thread safety issue), "random" still does not mean "unique". So there still could be some same numbers (from time to time). If you do need *unique* random numbers, the usual approach is to have all possible numbers in a pool and then randomly take (and remove) numbers from that pool. In your case, have a `new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 1500))`, and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're generating a new `Random` instance each time. Create the `Random` object once. As `Random` isn't thread safe, we'll need to use a random generator which is:

```
public static class ThreadSafeRandom 
{ 
    private static Random global = new Random(); 

    [ThreadStatic] 
    private static Random local;

    public static int Next() 
    { 
        Random inst = local; 
        if (inst == null) 
        { 
            int seed; 
            lock (global) 
            {
                seed = global.Next(); 
            }

            local = inst = new Random(seed); 
        } 

        return inst.Next(); 
    } 
}
```

And now consume it:

```
public TestClass
{
     public Task<int> GetRandomNumber() 
     {
         return Task.FromResult(ThreadSafeRandom.Next());
     }
}
```

**Edit:**

As a side note, you're executing your delegate on a threadpool thread and immediately synchronously blocking on it with `Result`. I'm assuming what you want to do is execute these in parallel:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = new TestClass();

    Task<int>[] addData = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
                                    .Select(_ => Task.Run(() => test.GetRandomNumber()))
                                    .ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(addData);
    foreach (var result in addData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The values that will be added are :{0}", result.Result);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The value is :{0}", adddata.Select(x => x.Result).Sum());
}
```

**Edit 2:**

As per @ChrisL correctly pointing out `Random` isn't thread safe, I've modified the code to use the a thread-safe random generator provided by [the PFX team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx).

Comment: The msdn article I linked states this is a common and incorrect solution - is that article wrong?

Comment: @ChrisL You're right. Yuval correctly points out that the OP is generating instances of `Random` in quick succession, but as your answer points out, generating one instance shared by all threads isn't the correct solution either.

Comment: @ChrisL You're right. I've modified the code with the thread-safe generator provided by the PFX team. Thanks for pointing that out, I've learned something as well :)

Comment: @downvoter - Would be nice to know what you find wrong about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post here: [Thread safe random number generation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx)

In short: Random() is not thread safe, nor was it designed to be.

Comment: The instances of `Random` he's creating are local, they're not being shared.

Comment: @dcastro You're right, I overlooked that. Thanks.